# Update a mySql table in Android with HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, php, android, mysql, httpurlconnection

I need to update a mysql table in Android I tried to use `Post` method but doesn't work, please help me.
I have created a php page for receive "`id`" from Android app. Theoretically App send "`id`" throw `HttpUrlConnection` when `download()` is executed but doesn't work, I don't understand how use it.
I apologize for my bad English.

This is my **php**

```
 <?php 
 if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'){
 //Getting values 
 $id = $_POST['id'];



 //importing database connection script 
 require_once('dbConnect.php');

 //Creating sql query 
 $sql = "UPDATE tbl_mp3 SET Download=Download+1 WHERE id = $id";

 //Updating database table 
 if(mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
 echo 'DownloadUpdated Successfully';
 }else{
 echo 'Could Not Update Download Try Again';
 }

 //closing connection 
 mysqli_close($con);
 }
```

and this is my **MainActivity.java**

```
public void countdownload() throws Exception {

        URL url = new URL("myphp");
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(15000);
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);


       String id=Constant.TAG_ID;


        OutputStream os = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(
                new OutputStreamWriter(os, "UTF-8"));
        writer.write(id);
        writer.flush();
        writer.close();
        os.close();

        urlConnection.connect();


    }

    private void download() throws Exception {
        File root = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + getString(R.string.download_desti));

        if(!root.exists()) {
            root.mkdirs();
        }

        File file = new File(root,Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Name()+".mp3");

        if(!file.exists()) {
            String url = Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Url();
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url));
            request.setDescription(getResources().getString(R.string.downloading) + " - " + Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Name());
            request.setTitle(Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Name());
            // in order for this if to run, you must use the android 3.2 to compile your app
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
                request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
                request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
            }
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(getString(R.string.download_desti), Constant.arrayList_play.get(Constant.playPos).getMp3Name() + ".mp3");

            // get download service and enqueue file
            DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            manager.enqueue(request);
            //add 1 to dowload string on DB
            this.countdownload();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getResources().getString(R.string.already_download), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

I don't understand how use `Httpconnection`.
Thank you for your help.

Comment: It falls down? Add your logcat.

Comment: no doesn't falls simply the database doesn't come updated

Comment: So, try read connections inputstream: `urlConnection.getInputStream()` to get server response.

Comment: still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use OkHttp provided by square. This is so simple to use.
Link for OkHttp https://square.github.io/okhttp/